# Reverse Engineering a transmitter circuit

Tags: transmitter, reverse-engineering

This circuit is from a radio transmitter electric gate keyfob. -> http://www.easygates.co.uk/product_info.asp?ProductID=340

I want to make my own keyfob.

How would I go about finding or creating a circuit diagram for this? I've tried to search for the main chip but couldn't find anything.

Cheers
[image]

Comment: Don't worry about the original circuit.  Identify the frequency of operation from the FCC ID and online filings.  Then use a receiver for that to see if the transmission is always the same, or if it changes.  If you don't have a receiver, you can likely see OOK transmissions as current draw on the power line, for example making a coupling transformer between the the battery lead and a PC sound card.  Or you can rig a "crystal radio" type RF power detector with an RF diode - just get the capacitance right so that the decay time is short enough to see the data pulses.

Comment: Buy a 20 dollar RTL-SDR dongle to see RF protocol, shop for major manufacture supporting that band/modulation